# Yeoman Generator

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет! Возникла потребность сделать свой генератор проекта.

После установки самого yeoman generator командой:

```
npm install -g yo generator-generator
```

запускаю сам генератор командой:

```
yo generator
```

После возникает ошибка:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\yo\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules \rx\dist\rx.js:579
    throw e;
          ^ Error: Cannot find module 'yeoman-environment'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user303\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gen erator-generator\node_modules\yeoman-generator\index.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user303\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gen erator-generator\app\index.js:4:18)
```

Пробовала установить сам модуль `yeoman-environment` , но все безуспешно.

Установлено на Windows: **yo 1.4.6, node v0.10.32, npm 2.8.3**
пробовала "лечить" проблему с помощью

```
npm cache clear && npm install -gf yo && npm install -gf generator-name
```

Но не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону искать ответ? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблему путем объявления системных переменных PATH и NODE_PATH

```
Path = ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
Node_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules
```

чтобы узнать точный путь, использовала:

```
npm prefix -g
```